# Only some values are editing with a form Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am using a form and I don't know why I can edit with it the values except in the fields `apellido` and `cedula`.

I am using the same logic in all the form fields so I dunno what can be causing it.

I'm gonna post the code of the view, controller, and model.

**View**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Editar Médico</h1>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('medico.update', $medico) }}">
                            @csrf
                            @method('PUT')
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="nombre" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nombre') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control @error('nombre') is-invalid @enderror" name="nombre" value="{{ $medico->nombre}}" required autocomplete="nombre" autofocus>
                                    @error('nombre')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>                                                        
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="apellido" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Apellido') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="apellido" type="text" class="form-control @error('apellido') is-invalid @enderror" name="apellido" value="{{ $medico->apellido}}" required autocomplete="apellido" autofocus>
                                    @error('apellido')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>                                                        
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="cedula" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Cédula') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="cedula" type="text" class="form-control @error('cedula') is-invalid @enderror" name="apellido" value="{{ $medico->cedula}}" required autocomplete="cedula" autofocus>
                                    @error('cedula')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>                                                        
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Email') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ $medico->email}}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                                    @error('email')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>                                                        
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="telefono" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Teléfono') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="telefono" type="text" class="form-control @error('telefono') is-invalid @enderror" name="telefono" value="{{ $medico->telefono}}" required autocomplete="telefono" autofocus>
                                    @error('telefono')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>                                                        
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="direccion" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Dirección') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="direccion" type="text" class="form-control @error('direccion') is-invalid @enderror" name="apellido" value="{{ $medico->direccion}}" required autocomplete="direccion" autofocus>
                                    @error('direccion')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>                                                        
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="ciudadResi" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Ciudad de Residencia') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="ciudadResi" type="text" class="form-control @error('ciudadResi') is-invalid @enderror" name="apellido" value="{{ $medico->ciudadResi}}" required autocomplete="ciudadResi" autofocus>
                                    @error('ciudadResi')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>                                                        
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="fechaNacimiento" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Fecha de Nacimiento') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="fechaNacimiento" type="date" class="form-control @error('fechaNacimiento') is-invalid @enderror" name="fechaNacimiento" value="{{ $medico->fechaNacimiento}}" required autocomplete="fechaNacimiento" autofocus>
                                    @error('fechaNacimiento')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>                                                        
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="genero" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Genero') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="genero" type="text" class="form-control @error('genero') is-invalid @enderror" name="genero" value="{{ $medico->genero}}" required autocomplete="genero" autofocus>
                                    @error('genero')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>                                                        
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Editar') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**Controller**

```
public function updateMedico(Request $request, $id) {
    $medico = Persona::findOrFail($id);
    $medico->fill($request->all());
    if($medico ->save()) {
        return redirect()->route('personaMostrarMedicos');
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('medico.edit');
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public $timestamps =false;

protected $fillable = [
    'nombre',
    'apellido',
    'cedula',
    'email',
    'telefono',
    'direccion',
    'ciudadResi',
    'fechaNacimiento',
    'genero',
    'estado',
    'idTipoPersona'
];
```

I have no idea what could be wrong because only those 2 fields I mention are the ones I can't update, the other ones are fine.

In case it can helps this is also my database model

[image: Database Model]

After using `dd($request->all());` in the controller this is the output

[image: Output of dd($request->all()]

What I have in the form before clicking the update button and the output of `dd($request->all())`

[image: Form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the problem, but you have 2 `name="apellido"`, check `cedula`, it has that `name`, so that is wrong.

Remember that when you send a form, the way to get the value is going to use the `name` property and not the `id` as that is pure CSS.

Change this:

```html
<input id="cedula" type="text" class="form-control @error('cedula') is-invalid @enderror" name="apellido" value="{{ $medico->cedula}}" required autocomplete="cedula" autofocus>
```

To this:

```html
<input id="cedula" type="text" class="form-control @error('cedula') is-invalid @enderror" name="cedula" value="{{ $medico->cedula }}" required autocomplete="cedula" autofocus>
```

Comment: That solved the cedula problem but apellido still doesn't updates

Comment: it was the same mistake, forget about it

Comment: Sorry, didn´t figured out you answer was first @matiaslauriti. I alrady changed for you to get the right answer. I already fixed and made your answer the right one but before I also gave you one point. If you were the one that place the downvote in the question Can you take it back please, as I already fixed the issue and placed your answer as the right one? I apology for my mistake and any inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

You have two inputs with the same name `apellido` this is why it isn't working properly.

Change this -

```
<input id="cedula" type="text" class="form-control @error('cedula') is-invalid @enderror" name="apellido" value="{{ $medico->cedula}}" required autocomplete="cedula" autofocus>
```

To this -

```
<input id="cedula" type="text" class="form-control @error('cedula') is-invalid @enderror" name="cedula" value="{{ $medico->cedula}}" required autocomplete="cedula" autofocus>
```

It should be working then.

Comment: I did what you say and cedula is now working but apellido still doesnt update

Comment: added the database model @Ramanath also in case it can help with the issue

Comment: use `dd($request->all())`  in the controller method. What is the output?

Comment: if I change a value it changes but the apellido one stays the same. Already posted what it shows in the question @Ramanath.

Comment: Also added now what values I have in the form before I click the update button @Ramanath

Comment: Forget about it, it was the same mistake in different views. Sorry for all the trouble but it was usefull to learn.

Comment: Nice, I replied first and he gets all the points. Use a good IDE next time, as this mistake is a 10 minutes new developer mistake...

Comment: @matiaslauriti as you can see I recognize and already fixed my issue, do you think if you were the one that downvoted my question please take it back. Sorry for any inconvenience.